# После отключения пользователя в Active Directory плагин Jenkins "AD" ругается на ненайденного пользователя, хотя используется уже другой пользователь

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, active-directory

Имеется сервер Jenkins(2.249.2) на "Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"  и плагин [Active Directory](https://plugins.jenkins.io/active-directory/)(2.24) + Матричное распределение прав.

Данный плагин подключался к серверу AD под пользователем 1, но теперь этот пользователь заблокирован и в настройках указан пользователь 2.
Авторизация работает корректно, но в лог Jenkins попадает ошибка, ссылающаяся на старого пользователя, хотя на странице настройки, в config.xml и в матричной таблице этот пользователь отсутствует:

```
2021-07-04 04:38:06.436+0000 [id=18161381]      WARNING h.p.a.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl#bind: Failed to authenticate while binding to 192.168.0.100:389
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090453, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 533, v3839^@]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3261)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3207)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2993)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2907)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2799)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2772)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.reconnect(LdapCtx.java:2697)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:668)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:546)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.lambda$retrieveUser$0(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:412)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2405)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2403)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2386)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:454)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:297)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:223)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.authenticate(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:830)
        at hudson.security.AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.doAuthenticate(AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.java:72)
        at hudson.security.AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.access$000(AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.java:31)
        at hudson.security.AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm$Authenticator.retrieveUser(AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.java:106)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:122)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:200)
        at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:47)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderRealPasswordAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicHeaderRealPasswordAuthenticator.java:56)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:79)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1369)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1284)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:272)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-07-04 04:38:06.438+0000 [id=18161381]      WARNING h.p.a.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider#retrieveUser: Credential exception trying to authenticate against domain.com domain
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: Either no such user 'CN=user1,OU=Disconnected users,DC=domain,DC=com' or incorrect password
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:561)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.lambda$retrieveUser$0(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:412)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2405)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2403)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2386)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:454)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:297)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:223)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.authenticate(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:830)
        at hudson.security.AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.doAuthenticate(AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.java:72)
        at hudson.security.AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.access$000(AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.java:31)
        at hudson.security.AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm$Authenticator.retrieveUser(AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.java:106)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:122)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:200)
        at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:47)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderRealPasswordAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicHeaderRealPasswordAuthenticator.java:56)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:79)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1369)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1284)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:272)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```